# Difference in Browser and tab close event for beforeunload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-close

I'm working with Reactjs and have this requirement where I need to differentiate between Browser close event and Tab close event.
I'm using 'beforeunload' for this, but the event is called for both the events (browser and tab close).

My code looks like this -

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleUnload);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleUnload);
}
 
 handleUnload(e) {
    var message = "\o/";
    console.log(window.event);
    (e || window.event).returnValue = message; //Gecko + IE
    return message;
 }
```

Can Someone tell me how can I differentiate for these two events.

Comment: Just curious, what do you need this for? The user is leaving your webpage regardless.

Comment: It is totally on the requirement basis for the expiry of the user session.

Comment: So you want to delete a cookie only when the user closes the browser, not when they close a tab, right?

Comment: Yes @SergiuParaschiv